# ParametricNDSolve and FindFit

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I would like to fit a list of data:

```
data={{x1,y1},...,{xn,yn}}
```

My starting point is ParametricNDSolve with parameters a and b:

```
sol=ParametricNDSolve[{eq1,eq2,eq3,initcond},{f1,f2,f3},{t,0,10000},{a,b}]
```

The equations I want to fit to the data are:

```
x[a,b][t]=f1sin[f2]cos[f3]
y[a,b][t]=f2sin[f2]sin[f3]
```

I was trying to use FindFit but I have some trouble in defining the model.

```
model[a_,b_][t]={{x,y}}
fit=FindFit[data,model[a,b][t],{{a,0,1},{b,10,20}},t]
```

Can you help me with the syntax in defining the model? Because I only found examples where the equations to fit are directly taken from the solver.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you like the standard code? Show your code.

Comment: I modified my question

Comment: Is it typo `y[a,b][t]=f2sin[f2]sin[f3] `?

Comment: yes is f1sin[f2]sin[f3]

Comment: Please provide the undefined quantities: `eq1`, `eq1`, and `eq3`. Otherwise, it's difficult for us to  help you.  In addition, it would be useful if you could give us a *simplified* (perhaps contrived) version of what you are trying to do. That will both  make it easier for us to help *and* serve the purpose of helping you figure out how to solve this problem.